# Json from JS file, parse in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a js file with `JSON` in it (no code) something like that:

```
Name1 = {
    p1:0,
    p2:1,
    p3:2
};

Name2 = {
    p1:"None",
    p2:"Snappy",
    p3:"gzip"
};
```

and I want to parse it in C#, but the `Newtonsoft.JSON` doesn't know how to manage the `"Name = "`.
How can I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably because neither of those are valid JSON.

Comment: provide more clarification.

Comment: You can solve this by having using the [real JSON syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp)

Comment: The part *after* the `=` would be valid Json, `Name =` is just JavaScript so the assumption that there is *"no code"* is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, neither of those are valid JSON strings.

**An example of your structure as valid JSON**

```
{
  "Name": {
    "p1": 0,
    "p2": 1,
    "p3": 3
  }
}
```

**AND**

```
{
  "Name": {
    "p1": "None",
    "p2": "Snappy",
    "p3": "gzip"
  }
}
```

These would require a **root object** when deserializing.

E.g. your class structure would look something like:

```
public class RootObject {
     public Name Name {get; set;}
}

public class Name {
     public string p1 {get; set;}
     public string p2 {get; set;}
     public string p3 {get; set;}
}
```

And would be deserialized like this:

```
var json = ...; //Load from file or whatever.
var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
var p1 = myObj.Name.p1;
```

Comment: but he's file doesn't look like you described

Comment: Care to elaborate? @styx

Comment: how did you convert the original question the legitimate JSON file @ThePerplexedOne

Comment: @styx I wrote it.

Comment: i mean, in code, he's text file is NOT a valid JSON @ThePerplexedOne

Comment: Yes, welcome to half an hour ago. I rewrote his JSON so that it would be valid for deserialization.

Comment: you can just alter the question so it would fit your needs 
@ThePerplexedOne

Comment: @styx I'm not responding to you anymore. No offense.

Answer (score 0):

convert your file to legitimate JSON string and then parse it

```
string data = //get your data somehow - (ex.loading from file)
int indexStart;
data = data.Replace(";", String.Empty);
while ((indexStart = data.IndexOf("{")) > 0)
{
   //convert the set of data to be legetimate JSON string         
   int indexEnd = data.IndexOf("}");
   string temp = data.Substring(indexStart, indexEnd - indexStart + 1);
   //Deserializ string
   var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeData>(temp);
   //prepare the data for the next iteration
   data = data.Substring(indexEnd + 1);
}
```

and the class that suits the JSON format

```
public class SomeData
{
    public string p1 { get; set; }
    public string p2 { get; set; }
    public string p3 { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

this is a code to parse your string

```
class name {
        public dynamic p1 { get; set; }
        public dynamic p2 { get; set; }
        public dynamic p3 { get; set; }
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string code = @"Name1 = {
p1:0,
p2:1,
p3:2
};

Name2 = {
p1:""None"",
p2: ""Snappy"",
p3: ""gzip""
};";

        List<name> l = new List<name>();
        string[] partsBySamicolon = code.Split(';'); 

        foreach(string s in partsBySamicolon){
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            {
                string[] partByBraces = s.Split('{');
                name n = new name();


                string[] partsbyComma = partByBraces[1].Split('}')[0].Split(',');
                foreach (string ss in partsbyComma)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ss))
                    {
                        if (ss.Contains("p1"))
                            n.p1 = ss.Split(':')[1].Trim();

                            if (ss.Contains("p2"))
                            n.p2 = ss.Split(':')[1].Trim();

                        if (ss.Contains("p3"))
                            n.p3 = ss.Split(':')[1].Trim();
                    }
                }
                l.Add(n);
            }

        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: What the heck is this mess?

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne this heck covert string to object as string is given in Question.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  You *could* write code to parse JSON (though I have no idea if this even works), but there are already well-tested libraries to do it for you.  A good example is Newtonsoft's JSON.NET, which is a NuGet package.  Whenever I see code like this, which mimics an existing library that millions of people already use, all I see is a giant red flag.